# How does one avoid loading multiple asdf files for a common lisp project?

Tags: common-lisp, slime, quicklisp

While working through Peter Seibel's book *Practical Common Lisp*, I've had some difficulty understanding how to handle the Common Lisp package system in conjunction with Emacs's SLIME and quicklisp. The project he supplies has the following structure:

- `spam.lisp` in the package `com.gigamonkeys.spam`, which relies on two other packages, `cl-ppcre` and `com.gigamonkeys.pathnames`.
- `pathnames.lisp` in the package `com.gigamonkeys.pathnames`
- `spam.asd`, which describes the dependencies of `com.gigamonkeys.spam` package
- `pathnames.asd`, which describes the dependencies of the `com.gigamonkeys.pathnames` package

The only way that I've currently found to build the final target, spam.lisp, is to:

1. Compile and load the `pathnames.asd` file using SLIME (`C-x C-k`)
2. Load the `com.gigamonkeys.pathname` package by typing `(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op 'spam)`  at the REPL
3. Load the `cl-ppcre` package by typing `(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")` at the REPL
4. Compile and load the `spam.asd` file using SLIME
5. Load the `com.gigamonkeys.spam` package by typing `(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op 'spam)` at the REPL

This seems like an insane amount of work required to use the functions defined in a single file (`spam.lisp`) - I've got to be doing something wrong. Is there some way to load `spam.lisp` and, recursively, its dependencies, with fewer commands?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

[Source + Full Story](https://web.archive.org/web/20171127051637/http://weitz.de:80/packages.html)

Long story short, packages are bags of symbols and systems describe
relationships between files and other systems.

So, using your structure here is a simple system definition:

```
(asdf:defsystem #:spam-filter
  :serial t
  :description "Simple Spam Filter"
  :author "PCL"
  :depends-on (#:cl-ppcre
               #:com.gigamonkeys.pathnames)

  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "spam")))
```

Now, I'll suppose the system `com.gigamonkeys.pathnames` is in
`~/src/lisp/com/gigamonkeys/pathnames/` and the spam filter in
`~/src/lisp/spam-filter/`.

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`slime`<kbd>RET</kbd>
2. <kbd>,cd</kbd>~/src/lisp/com/gigamonkeys/pathnames<kbd>RET</kbd>
3. `(push (truename ".") asdf:*central-registry*)`
4. <kbd>,cd</kbd>~/src/lisp/spam-filter<kbd>RET</kbd>
5. `(push (truename ".") asdf:*central-registry*)`
6. `(ql:quickload :spam-filter)`

Because Quicklisp relies on ASDF to load systems, you've to add the systems directories
in ASDF search-path.

You could also put your systems in Quicklisp's search path by adding
them in `~/quicklisp/local-projects/`. You can either store your code
there or use symbolic links.

PS: You can find 
[here](https://github.com/daimrod/Emacs-config/blob/master/config-slime.el#L76)
a slime-shortcut that allows me to write <kbd>,add</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>
instead of `(push (truename ".") asdf:*central-registry*)`.

And just below another slime-shortcut to quickload a system.
(<kbd>,ql</kbd>`some-system-name`<kbd>RET</kbd>)

Comment: I apologize for the delay in marking this as correct, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 3):

A little bit terminology:

- a *[Package](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_.htm)* is a Common Lisp standard feature. A package is a namespace for symbols. Nothing more. It is not a *file*, not a *module*, not a *library* and not tied to any such thing. It's not even a namespace for functions, variables or classes. Just for symbols. There is a convention to put the definitions that setup a package into a file of its own. But that is just a convention.
- a *System* is used to define, load and compile all files which make up a software library or application. The idea of a *System* is old (over thirty years). [ASDF](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/) (Another System Definition Facility) is a popular and free implementation of that idea. Kent Pitman wrote in 1984 about [The Description of Large Systems](http://nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Large-Systems.html).

A part of such a system facility is a registry, from where all systems can be found. A system definition describes the files it consists of and all the systems it depends on. Typically such a registry is a directory in the file system and/or a registry (a variable, ...) in a running Lisp.

On loading a particular system, the system tool looks into the registry and finds it, loads the definition, loads recursively all needed systems, and then loads all the files.

See the ASDF manual: [Configuring ASDF to find your systems](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Configuring-ASDF.html#Configuring-ASDF)